# What is the role of decorators for cron functions?

Tags: cron, odoo, python-decorators, odoo-13

odoo - 13.0

I recently faced the below error in cron jobs. It was working fine for months

```
ValueError: <class 'AttributeError'>: "'model' object has no attribute 'my_function'" while evaluating 'model.my_function()'
```

Upon googling, found suggestions to add `@api.model` decorator to the function. I did and error was gone.

Anyone could explain why cron job needed that decorator ? It would be really helpful to understand what made it fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer Odoo official documentation to get knowledge about method decorators.Check the below link.

[Odoo Documentation - Method decorators](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/reference/addons/orm.html#module-odoo.api)

Answer (score 0):

the decorator specific that it is an external invocation function where no id is called, additional the method converts old API calls to the decorated function to new API signature.

However, [this URL form will be useful](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/api-model-and-api-multi-what-s-the-difference-145883.)